# The difference made my a 5400/7200RPM hdd in a MBP

Tags: mac, hard-drive, macbook-pro

In a MacBook pro 13" with a 2.7 ghz dual core i7 plus 4GB of RAM - how much difference would a 5400RPM hdd make to a 7200RPM hdd in terms of turning on, opening programs, and then running the programs?

Comment: I probably would go with higher cache. If 5400RPM has 32MB Cache and 7200RPM has 16MB Cache the difference is negligible. So in other words if you have money you could go for 7200RPM and possibly 64MB Cache. Or the Hybrid Hard Drive.

Comment: the hybrid hard drive - thats the one made my samsung that has flash and a HDD in the enclosure isnt it?

Comment: @ Sammy - What I was thinking was [Seagate HHD](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/laptops/laptop-hdd/)

Comment: I wrestled with the same decision before I bought my MacBook. Mostly because I dreaded the HD performance on my client issued Dell D630 for work.

Answer (score 2):

There are many other factors besides spin rate to consider in such a comparison; as Darius mentioned cache is important too.

If all things were equal besides the spin rate, the increase would give you about a 33% faster access to your data (+1800 RPM).

Other things you want to look at are access time and random write speeds. All 7200 hard drives are not created equal.

Comment: kl thanx - how much difference would the faster spin rate make to battery life dyou know?

Comment: I don't really have the specs to answer that question, but I can only assume it would be negligible. Also, if you were to increase the areal density of the drive (i.e. 500GB -> 1TB) the data transfer rate is increased while keeping the rotational speed the same since more data is read by the head, yet the drive is the same physical size. So a 500GB 7200RPM drive could be as fast in transfer speed as a 1TB 5400RPM drive due to more data reaching the head per spin over time (RPM).